# Repeating values in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following values in a column which are separated by comma.

```
BHOP23,BHOP23,BHOP24
```

I would like to know whether values are repeating in a column.

How can I do this?

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: @jarlh This is a temprory table to load data to main table.

Comment: Do you need to check if the string contains duplicated values or to get a different string, containing only non duplicated vaues? If so, do you need to preserve the ordering of the initial string?

Comment: @Aleksej I need to get a string with no duplicate or non repeating strings, no need to preserve the ordering. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( your_list_column ) AS
  SELECT 'a,a,b,c,d' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- duplicates both at head
  SELECT 'a,b,a,c,d' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- duplicates at head and middle
  SELECT 'a,b,c,d,a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- duplicates at head and tail
  SELECT 'a,b,b,c,d' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- duplicates at middle and next item
  SELECT 'a,b,c,b,d' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- duplicates at middle and middle
  SELECT 'a,b,c,d,b' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- duplicates at middle and tail
  SELECT 'a,b,c,d,d' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- duplicates both at tail
  SELECT 'a,b,a,c,b' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- two pairs of duplicates
  SELECT 'a,b,c,d,e' FROM DUAL;          -- no duplicates
```

To get the lists which have repeated values, you can use a back-reference in a regular expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( ',' || your_list_column || ',', ',([^,]+),(.+,)?\1,' )
```

**Output**:

```
YOUR_LIST_COLUMN
----------------
a,a,b,c,d
a,b,a,c,d
a,b,c,d,a
a,b,b,c,d
a,b,c,b,d
a,b,c,d,b
a,b,c,d,d
a,b,a,c,b
```

To get the first repeated value you can extract the first sub-group of the above regular expression:

```
SELECT your_list_column,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( ',' || your_list_column || ',', ',([^,]+),(.+,)?\1,', 1, 1, NULL, 1 )
         AS duplicate_value
FROM   your_table
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( ',' || your_list_column || ',', ',([^,]+),(.+,)?\1,' )
```

**Output**:

```
YOUR_LIST_COLUMN DUPLICATE VALUE
---------------- ---------------
a,a,b,c,d        a
a,b,a,c,d        a
a,b,c,d,a        a
a,b,b,c,d        b
a,b,c,b,d        b
a,b,c,d,b        b
a,b,c,d,d        d
a,b,a,c,b        a
```

To get the unique values then, use the [`split_string()` function as defined here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170914140540/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/1968/splitting-delimited-strings) (but using a user-defined type rather than a pre-defined `VARRAY`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE stringlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN stringlist DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       stringlist := stringlist();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/
```

Then you can use it in conjunction with the `SET()` collection function:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (
         SELECT LISTAGG( COLUMN_VALUE, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM )
         FROM   TABLE( SET( split_string( t.your_list_column ) ) )
       ) AS unique_list
FROM   your_table t
```

**Output**:

```
YOUR_LIST_COLUMN UNIQUE_LIST
---------------- ---------------
a,a,b,c,d        a,b,c,d
a,b,a,c,d        a,b,c,d
a,b,c,d,a        a,b,c,d
a,b,b,c,d        a,b,c,d
a,b,c,b,d        a,b,c,d
a,b,c,d,b        a,b,c,d
a,b,c,d,d        a,b,c,d
a,b,a,c,b        a,b,c
a,b,c,d,e        a,b,c,d,e
```

Comment: Thanks you, how can I get unique values from a column?

Comment: @user75ponic What column? Do you mean the unique values from the list?

Comment: @user75ponic Updated - a better solution would be not to store lists as character strings and put the list items into a separate table.

Comment: Thanks for the update, however I am still able to see repeated values.

Comment: @user75ponic Please update your question with a [MCVE] - I do not have your data, cannot see your query and have no idea why you are still seeing duplicates as the query I posted works on my sample data.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A PL/SQL function which only relies on simple string functions (`SUBSTR`, `INSTR` and `LENGTH`) to remove duplicates from a string list:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5da19/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( your_list_column ) AS
  SELECT 'a,a,b,c,d' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- duplicates both at head
  SELECT 'a,b,a,c,d' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- duplicates at head and middle
  SELECT 'a,b,c,d,a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- duplicates at head and tail
  SELECT 'a,b,b,c,d' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- duplicates at middle and next item
  SELECT 'a,b,c,b,d' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- duplicates at middle and middle
  SELECT 'a,b,c,d,b' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- duplicates at middle and tail
  SELECT 'a,b,c,d,d' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- duplicates both at tail
  SELECT 'a,b,a,c,b' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- two pairs of duplicates
  SELECT 'a,b,c,d,e' FROM DUAL           -- no duplicates
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remove_Duplicates_From_List(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       VARCHAR2(4000) := i_delim;
  p_temp         VARCHAR2(4000);
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_temp := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end + c_ld - p_start );
      IF INSTR( p_result, i_delim || p_temp ) = 0 THEN
        p_result := p_result || p_temp;
      END IF;
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_temp := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 ) || i_delim;
      IF INSTR( p_result, i_delim || p_temp ) = 0 THEN
        p_result := p_result || p_temp;
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN SUBSTR( p_result, c_ld + 1, LENGTH( p_result ) - 2 * c_ld );
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT your_list_column,
       remove_Duplicates_From_List( your_list_column ) AS uniq
FROM   your_table
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5da19/1/0)**:

```
| YOUR_LIST_COLUMN |      UNIQ |
|------------------|-----------|
|        a,a,b,c,d |   a,b,c,d |
|        a,b,a,c,d |   a,b,c,d |
|        a,b,c,d,a |   a,b,c,d |
|        a,b,b,c,d |   a,b,c,d |
|        a,b,c,b,d |   a,b,c,d |
|        a,b,c,d,b |   a,b,c,d |
|        a,b,c,d,d |   a,b,c,d |
|        a,b,a,c,b |     a,b,c |
|        a,b,c,d,e | a,b,c,d,e |
```