# Oracle query to match all values in the list among all rows in table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table structure as under:

```
ID    A     B
--   ---  -----
 1    a     a1
 2    b     b1
 3    a     a2
 4    c     a1
 5    b     b2
```

I want such values from column A, who are related to ALL the values of B in a list.

For Example:

I have a list of A's:

```
{a1,a2}
```

Output should be `a`,
`c` is `NOT` returned in the result because it is related to `a1` only and not `a2`.

Is there a way to get this result by a SQL query?

**Edited**

It should work in this special case:

```
ID    A     B
--   ---  -----
 1    a     a1
 2    b     b1
 3    a     a2
 4    c     a1
 5    b     b2
 6    c     a3
 7    c     a2
```

Now `c` is also related to `a2` and `a3`, but it should NOT be returned because for being a part of result, `c` should be related to exactly `a1` AND `a2`

But if I query as follows:

```
SELECT A
FROM   table_name
WHERE  B IN ( 'a1', 'a2' )      -- The items in the list
GROUP BY A
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT b ) = 2;
```

It returns `c` too.

Comment: How is the list of values given? Is it a string containing a list of values, the result of a query, ... ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, A, B ) AS
SELECT 1,    'a',     'a1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    'b',     'b1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,    'a',     'a2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,    'c',     'a1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,    'b',     'b2' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query - Use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT( DISTINCT ... )`**:

```
SELECT A
FROM   table_name
WHERE  B IN ( 'a1', 'a2' )      -- The items in the list
GROUP BY A
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT b ) = 2; -- The number of items in the list
```

**Output**:

```
A
-
a
```

**Query - Passing the list dynamically**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE stringlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10);
/

SELECT A
FROM   table_name
WHERE  B MEMBER OF :your_list
GROUP BY A
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT B ) = CARDINALITY( :your_list );
```

*Where the bind variable `:your_list` is of type `stringlist`.*

If the list is passed as a delimited string then you can use any of the techniques in the [Splitting delimited strings](https://web.archive.org/web/20170914140540/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/1968/splitting-delimited-strings) documentation page to separate it. There is a simple [PL/SQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42484482/1509264) that would return it as a collection that could be plugged into the above query.

**Update**:

```
SELECT A
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY A
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN b IN ( 'a1', 'a2' )     THEN b END ) = 2
AND    COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN b NOT IN ( 'a1', 'a2' ) THEN b END ) = 0;
```

or

```
SELECT A
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY A
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN b MEMBER OF :your_list     THEN b END ) = CARDINALITY( :your_list )
AND    COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN b NOT MEMBER OF :your_list THEN b END ) = 0;
```

Comment: @MTO this works! Except in one case: I added this special case in the question. Could you please take a look.

Comment: @OutOfMind It works for your "special case" as well. The `WHERE` clause will filter to eliminate the `c`/`a3` row and then the `HAVING` clause will filter the `c` group as it only has `c`/`a1` remaining which is 1 distinct value not 2.

Comment: Oh right! 
Ok one more case that came to me:
What if `c` is related to `a1,a2,a3`, then it will be returned but as per my requirement it should not be.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `GROUP BY` and a `COUNT`.

```
SELECT A
FROM yourtable
WHERE B IN ('a1', 'a2')
GROUP BY A
HAVING Count(DISTINCT B) > 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT A      
FROM tablename   
WHERE B = 'a1'
OR B = 'a2'
```

I think this should do the trick. Distinct is added so the value 'a' in A will only display once.

Comment: This would return `c` even though it does not have an `a2` row in the original example.