# SQL Where condition with 2 contradicting clauses Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a list of elements, These elements have a "creator type" determined by one relation. This relation field value can be 1-2-3.

I have to make a sql query with the next conditions:

- Get all elements with value 1 and (2 or 3)
- Ignore elements with value 1 without 2 or 3.

SCHEDULES

```
ID|NAMEUNIQUE|STARTTIME|ENDTIME|STATUS|CREATOR|CREATOR_TYPE
1 |AAAAAAAAAA|.........|.......|......|.......|1
2 |BBBBBBBBBB|.........|.......|......|.......|2
3 |BBBBBBBBBB|.........|.......|......|.......|1
4 |CCCCCCCCCC|.........|.......|......|.......|3
5 |DDDDDDDDDD|.........|.......|......|.......|1
```

In this case, the query should return rows with ID 2,3,4,5 and discard 1 because is an unique schedule (AAAAAAAAAA) that not have creator type 2 or 3.

Sorry for my englisht, it's hard try to explan this to me

Comment: Don't forget to _specify_ the expected result too.

Comment: Please, show your current attempt and describe what is wrond with it. Hint: use `exists`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle query to match all values in the list among all rows in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42995405/oracle-query-to-match-all-values-in-the-list-among-all-rows-in-table)

Comment: Why would rows 4 and 5 be returned? Row 4 (uniquename = C) doesn't satisfy the 1st condition (it has creator type = 3, but doesn't have type 1). Row 5 (D) doesn't satisfy the 2nd condition (it has creator type, but doesn't have types 2 nor 3). Or did I misunderstand it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation in analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT s.*,
         COUNT(CASE creator_type WHEN 1 THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY nameunique) AS num_1s,
         COUNT(CASE creator_type WHEN 2 THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY nameunique) AS num_2s,
         COUNT(CASE creator_type WHEN 3 THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY nameunique) AS num_3s
  FROM   schedules s
)
WHERE num_1s > 0
AND   (num_2s > 0 OR num_3s > 0);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE schedules (id, nameunique, creator_type) AS
SELECT 1, 'AAAAA', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'BBBBB', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'BBBBB', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'CCCCC', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'CCCCC', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'DDDDD', 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | NAMEUNIQUE | CREATOR_TYPE | NUM_1S | NUM_2S | NUM_3S |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2 | BBBBB | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
> | 3 | BBBBB | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
> | 4 | CCCCC | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
> | 5 | CCCCC | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ee87bfb686fafe31b9e6b1d0d9292c0d)*

Comment: I believe you can merge num_2s and num_3s columns since OP needs "2 or 3". Like "... when creator_type in (2,3) then ...".

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from   (
         select s.*, 
                min(creator_type) over (partition by nameunique) as min_type,
                max(creator_type) over (partition by nameunique) as max_type
         from   schedules s
       )
where  min_type = 1 and max_type > 1
;
```