# Oracle - query to retrieve only values in column having the different associated values from another column in same table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a oracle sql query for the below.

The table “employee” contains columns: ENO, Sequence and Status of 3 employees.
I need  to retrieve only those employees who has Status as both "New" and "Old".  So, I do not need employee no: C456. Please see below expected output.

[image]

Final expected output is below:

[image]

Comment: Hint: Look up `not exists` or `not in`.

Comment: Hint: join table on itself.  Question looks like a homework exercise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle query to match all values in the list among all rows in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42995405/oracle-query-to-match-all-values-in-the-list-among-all-rows-in-table)

Answer (score 1):

You can use these queries:

```
1) select *
     from employee a
    where exists (select 1 from employee b where b.ENO = a.ENO and b.status = 'New')
      and exists (select 1 from employee b where b.ENO = a.ENO and b.status = 'Old')
    order by 1,2;

ENO    SEQUENCE STATUS
---- ---------- -------
A101          1 New
A101          2 Old
A101          3 Old
A101          4 Old
B111          3 Old
B111          5 New
B111         25 New

2) select *
     from employee a
    where (select count(distinct b.status) 
             from employee b where b.ENO = a.ENO and b.status in ('New','Old')) = 2
    order by 1,2;
              
ENO    SEQUENCE STATUS
---- ---------- -------
A101          1 New
A101          2 Old
A101          3 Old
A101          4 Old
B111          3 Old
B111          5 New
B111         25 New
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution using `count() over()` without `inner joins`.

```
select  ENO
       ,Sequence
       ,Status
from   (
        select  t.*
                  ,count(distinct status) over(partition by eno) as cnt
        from    t
       ) t
where   cnt = 2
```

| ENO | SEQUENCE | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A101 | 1 | New |
| A101 | 2 | Old |
| A101 | 3 | Old |
| A101 | 4 | Old |
| B111 | 25 | New |
| B111 | 5 | New |
| B111 | 3 | Old |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/U3OKvFwz)

Comment: How to handle and tweak this query in case the ‘sequence’ column is from another table called department? And the employee and department tables are joined by eno column.

Comment: just join first and then run the same thing `join using(eno)` and then run on both tables.

Comment: Somehow not working

Comment: send me a fiddle